# The meaning of "infinity" in a problem (Schaum, *General Topoplogy*, ex. 4.7)

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am working with problem 7, chapter 4 in Schaum's *General Topology*. The problem is as follows:

> *Prove:* Let $p$ accumulation point of $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then every open set containing $p$ contains an **infinite** number of points in $A$.

The proof is by contradiction; we assume that $G$ contains $p$ and a finite set of numbers from $A$, $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. Then we can find an open disc centered on $p$, which is a subset of $G$ and that does not contain any of the $a_i$, by taking the radius of the disc to be less than $\min d(p, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Thus $A \cap (G \setminus \{p\}) = \emptyset $, which contradicts the assumption that $p$ was an accumulation point of $A$.

I thought I understood the proof, but after thinking about the problem I got really confused. What is confusing me is the word "infinite". Even if we let $G$ contain $p$ and a countable infinity of numbers from $A$, $a_1, a_2, \ldots$, it looks like basically the same argument could be used to show that $p$ must be an accumulation point, or is this thought a mistake?

If so, it seems the proof should only work if "infinite" is taken to mean "uncountable infinity", right?

Comment: Minimum of infinitely many positive  numbers can be $0$  as in the case of $1,\frac  1 2 ,\frac 1 3,..$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: infnite just means "not finite", i.e not in bijection with one of the sets $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The contradiction comes from assuming it's finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give the definition so that we can go step by step here.

> **Definition:** An accumulation point $p \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a point such that for any neighbourhood $N$ of $p$, there is a
> point $a \in A, a \neq p$, such that $a \in N$.

Now as you say, the proof of your statement goes by contradiction. Suppose that we have an open set $G$ containing only a finite family of points in $A$. Denote this finite family $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Now we can take the open disk of radius less than the minimum of the distance from $p$ to any of the $a_i$, and then we've found a neighbourhood of $p$ containing no points of $A$, so that $p$ is in fact not an accumulation point of $A$.

You cannot apply the same argument in the case that $G$ contains an infinite family of points of $A$, because then we have to question what we mean by the "minimum distance from $p$ to any of the $a_i$". As remarked in the comments, if we allow a countably infinite family of points, the "minimum" does not have to be a positive number - it can be zero.

Indeed, the crux of the matter is that the minimum distance between $p$ and any member of a countably infinite set can be zero; the same proof does not in fact fly.

Comment: Thank you @Matt for the elaboration!